# How to get OS level information using Java?

Tags: java, operating-system

I am looking for a method or package in java where we can get OS level Information.

Is there any package equivalent to Management Object Searcher(c#) in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which OS native library you need to get the information you desire then call it using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Even i am looking to get information about bios, video and audio codecs, info related to network. is it possible?

Comment: @VivekAnand simply search for os libraries for bios,video, audio. Once you know which library will give the info, call it through JNI

Answer (score 1):

One simple line of code can do this.

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

and more specifically what OS level info you are looking ?

For memory related stuff you can have something like this.

```
System.out.println("Free memory (bytes): " + 
    Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());


long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

System.out.println("Total memory (bytes): " + 
    Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
```

Thanks

Comment: from Java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory() 
Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use not the OS memory

Answer (score 0):

Get `OperatingSystemMXBean` with

```
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
OperatingSystemMXBean os = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
```

get OS version or other available info.

Comment: Thanks. Will it work for getting bios, display, video and audio codecs, network, motherboard, memory information??

Comment: I dont think so, MX beans dont have such technical details. If you can find a util that prints that info, then you can run in from Java with Runtime.exec, collect and parse output

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this method in your code know the OS 

os.name

os.version

os.arch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get OS and it version by using below code snippet:

```
      String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");             
      System.out.println("Your OS is : " + OS);

      String OSVersion = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");             
      System.out.println("Your OS version is : " + OSVersion + " bit");
```